# ¿Porque no puedo filtrar los resultados diferentes de 0 con una propiedad Get sin Set?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net, mvc

estoy con una pequeña aplicacion en la cual requiero filtrar resultados por "Pagados" y "No Pagados" al momento de utilizar mi codigo .Where(p => p.Total != 0) para que me muestre todos los "No Pagados" me aparece un error: El valor no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parámetro: source. les muestro mi Modelo, Controlador y Error. Los resultados los muestro en un Datatable Jquery. Les adjunto imagen del error.[image: Imagen del error arrojado][image: Controlador en imagen]

```
public class Purchase
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public decimal Value { get { return PurchaseDetails.Sum(i => i.Value) - (decimal)Enganche; } }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public decimal Importe { get { return PurchaseDetails.Sum(i => i.Value); } }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public decimal Abonos { get { return (decimal)Enganche + (decimal)AddPayments.Sum(o => o.Abono); } }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public decimal Total { get { return PurchaseDetails.Sum(i => i.Value) - (decimal)Enganche - (decimal)AddPayments.Sum(o => o.Abono); } }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public decimal Saldo { get { return PurchaseDetails.Sum(i => i.Value) - (decimal)Enganche - (decimal)AddPayments.Sum(o => o.Abono); } }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public virtual State State { get; set; }

    public virtual Seller Seller { get; set; }

    public virtual Helper Helper { get; set; }

    public virtual House House { get; set; }

    public virtual TPayment TPayment { get; set; }

    public virtual DPayment DPayment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseDetail> PurchaseDetails { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AddPayment> AddPayments { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
        public JsonResult ListadoPendientes()
    {
        var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();

        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var purchases = db.Purchases.ToList().Where(p => p.Total != 0).Where(p => p.CompanyId == user.CompanyId).Select(p => new
        {
            CustomerName = p.Customer.Name,
            CustomerCliente = p.Customer.Cliente,
            p.PurchaseId,
            p.Ref,
            Address = p.Customer.Address,
            Colony = p.Customer.Colony,
            House = p.Customer.House.Name,
            CollectorName = p.Customer.Collector.Name,
        });

        var jsonResult = Json(purchases, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

Comment: Saludos Javier, ve por partes, primero mira cuál es el valor nulo exactamente.Podrías asignar variables que en caso haya un valor nulo, le asignes un 0.

Comment: no hay ningun valor nulo, anteriormente lo realizaba de esta manera: solo era con purchase = db.purchases.tolist() y en el webgrid aplicaba el .where(p => p.Total != 0) pero el webgrid es muy lento con tantos registros, por lo que requeri utilizar Datatable Jquery el cual funciona mucho mas rapido, sin embargo al utilizar estas tablas no me funcionan las propiedades de solo Get